# Show captcha after three wrong attempts by the user

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I am working on a application where at some places I need to introduce captcha if N number of attempts failed. These places can be signup, login, add to wishlist, subscribe etc. It is also to ensure that denial of service attack and brute force attack cannot be attempted by anyone. Is there a mechanism for this in Spring Security?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nothing in Spring Security directly, but it should be easy to store the login count in the users session and check that count in your JSP to render a CAPTCHA is neccessary.

Comment: Using the session to count attempts may not work well since cookies can be easily deleted which means a new session is created. Instead, you may want to consider logging the attempts per IP-address.

Comment: Which (at least for corporate users behind a NATting firewall) might easily lead to even more problems. :-)

Comment: I think a combination of the two is good. You could do 3 attempts for sessions and 6+ for ips. You could also make a captcha show for a specific account regardless of the user info.

Comment: I don't get how this is the accepted and most upvoted answer. The whole point of captcha is preventing scripted brute force attacks and the first thing that the bots are going to do is to not send cookies along with the request. It's probably even the default behavior in most cases.

Answer (score 7):

Implement an AuthenticationFailureHandler that updates a count/time in the DB. You can't count on using the session because the attacker is not going to be sending cookies anyway.

Answer (score 2):

[Implementation done using JCaptcha and SpringMVC](http://www.dagblog.cz/2005_11_20_archive.html)

http://parasjain.net/2008/11/11/jcaptcha-with-spring/

Comment: That is the nice blog however I am not able to understand how to show the captcha only after N number of times

Comment: @user504459, you can easily maintain a state, using session or cookie or querystring etc using an integer, increment it on every invalid attempt and if it exceeds threshold, use a RedirectView to show the captcha, how does it sound?

Comment: youps..Thanks it works ... every thing is working fine using this technique.

Comment: @Narayan what if the bot choose not to send this cookie with the nth login attempt

Comment: @MuhammadHewedy: In the case - store the userIP on each access attempt and identify the user based on IPaddress

Comment: Ip can changed using proxy

Comment: it depends on the scope of such captcha implementation; any complex Denial of Service attack that can spoof IP should look into handling the attack at network layer instead of application because someone with unlimited power can bring down even large scale website no matter if you catcha or not

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) with Spring Security, this is helpful http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/02/spring-security-3-integrating-recaptcha.html